# Help with volume of solids of revolution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

I have a region $R$ defined by $y=x^2$, $y=2+x$ and $x=0$.

How would be the integrals (no need to develop them) of the solid obtained by the revolution of $R$:

$a)$ around $x$-axis integrating in relation to $1)$ $x$ and $2)$ $y$?

$b)$ around $y$-axis integrating in relation to $1)$ $x$ and $2)$ $y$?

I just started studying calculus by myself and I would like to check some answers.

In the item a.1 I found $\int_0^2\pi|x^4-(1+x)^2| dx$. Is that correct? How would be the others?

Comment: Look up the shell method for integration.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not correct.

The correct formula is $V = \pi \int_a^b [f(x)]^2 \ dx$. The limits of integration are $x = 0, 2$ as you have said, but $f(x) = \text{top - bottom} = (2+x) - x^2$.

Comment: How can I find the a.2? Rotating around x-axis, but integrating in y

Comment: Use the shell method which is $V = \int_a^b 2 \pi x h \ dx$, where $h$ is the difference between the two functions, and you write the functions in terms of $y$. For more details, check the duplicate question I have linked or read your textbook: there are plenty of resources available, so it shows you need to research before asking.